# How to add libgif as a package in yocto build

Tags: linux, yocto

I am building yocto linux for embedded linux platform. 
The build is successful and root file system is generated.

however libgif.so library is missing in the root filesystem.

I want libgif to be compiled and copied in my generated root filesystem (in /usr/lib/)

I tried adding giflib in local.conf

`DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " giflib "`

I expect the giflib to be compiled and copied in the /usr/lib in root filesystem. but it isn't.

If i add EXTRA_IMAGEDEPENDS += " giflib " and just build giflib with "bitbake giflib" then the giflib is compiled and generated at path

`Build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/giflib/5.1.4-r0/build/lib/.libs/giflib.so`

Comment: As an add-on to Letos answer: you typically don't need to add pure library packages to your image explicitly: once you add an application that dynamically links with giflib, the correct giflib package will be added to the image automatically -- this is better because now it will also be removed automatically if your app no longer needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how it works, sorry.

1. Just building the package will not automagically install it into any rootfs
2. You have to tell bitbake that you want giflib to be included in your image. This is done by adding it to `IMAGE_INSTALL` of your custom image.
3. Adding it to `DISTRO_FEATURES` will probably have no effect at all, because that is only parsed for specific keywords.

This describes how to add something to a custom image: [Custom images in Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage-custombb). You can technically also go the local.conf routes mentioned in the paragraphs above the linked one, but that only hinders proper reproductibility. A bit more extensively, I explain it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqHylLP2NmA).